# WseWsdl3.exe Generates error on Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit

Tags: asp.net, wsdl, windows-7-x64

When I run the command :

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WSE\v3.0\Tools\WseWsdl3.exe" [WSDL location] /o:[file location] /l:cs /type:webClient
```

Where [WSDL location] is the location of the web service on my local machine and [file location] is the location to my webService.asmx.cs file location

I get the error:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Could not get the install directory for .NET F
ramework v2.0 SDK. Please install the .NET Framework v2.0 SDK.
   at WseWsdl.WebServiceUtil.RunWsdl(String[] args)
```

I google this kind of error and found one helpful link [WseWsdl3.exe Generates error on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit
by Robert Amiscaray 19. November 2009 11:31](http://www.enterpriseframework.com/post/2009/11/19/WseWsdl3exe-Generates-error-on-Windows-7-Ultimate-64-Bit.aspx)

I've made the suggested changes and still get the same error.
Is the blog entry right or I need to make some special changes b/c I'm using "Win 7 Pro Sp 1" ?

Comment: Were you aware that WSE is obsolete? It may not be supported at all on Windows 7. Also, have you tried doing what the error message says and installing the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Tell that to FedEx who has provided me with a WSDL containing an attachment and no instructions whatsoever

Comment: It would be up to you to tell FedEx. Someone who cares about the problem should help solve it. When it's my turn to care about FedEx, I'll do the same. My solution might involve telling my management why the FedEx API is unusable.

Answer (score 7):

The solution to the fix was to download :
[.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x64)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/f/7/8f72af82-dd19-49f9-b4a6-ecddb3990e4a/setup.exe)

And the execution worked out fine.....duh